# Greping text file

Tags: command-line, grep

I have text file:

```
Line1 aaa
Line2 aaa
Line3 aaa
Line4 importan info about Linux
Line5 infoA
Line6 infoB
Line7
```

I would like to display line containing word "Linux" and two lines more.

Regarding first part is clear:

```
cat textfile.txt |grep Linux
```

But how to display two lines more?

Answer (score 6):

Use the `-A` option of `grep`:

```
cat textfile.txt | grep -A2 Linux
```

or without the `cat`:

```
grep -A2 Linux textfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`Awk` alternative approach

```
$ awk '/Linux/ {print $0; for (i=1;i<=2;i++){ getline; print $0 } }' test-text-file.txt                               
Line4 importan info about Linux
Line5 infoA
Line6 infoB
```

Or as Pilot6 suggested in the coments, you can do

`awk '/Linux/{x=NR+2}(NR<=x)' test-text-file.txt`

Comment: In this case there is no need to use `awk`. This is an academic answer ;-) And there are lot of much easier ways even with `awk`.

Comment: @Pilot6 yes, no need for awk, but since Florian was the "faster gun" this time,  I cannot just post same answer. So I'm offering an alternative :)

Comment: You can omit `$0` twice, for instance ;-)

Comment: `awk '/Linux/{x=NR+2}(NR<=x){print}' file`

Comment: OK, that's a little simpler approach

Comment: And even `print` is not needed, since it is default.

Comment: `getline` is bad  =)